# How to extract data points in dynamic graphs to text file? (Datawrapper/html/json)

Tags: parsing, text, graph, extract

I want to extract the points in a text file for the linked graph (datawrapper) that appear when you move the cursor over the various plotted lines (different days, different proportions).

[This graph](https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/RE9Rq/1/) (looked at the code with "view-source:")

So far, I have only extracted single tables, for example, with BeautifulSoup or in R on simple HTML pages. In this case, I do not know what the most elegant approach would be.

What are common ways or solutions to solve this problem that I can dig into? Since I want to extract several such plots as tables, a solution that automates this would be desirable.

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late on this, but I hope this might be helpful. The graphics are generated by javascript--we can dig into the scripts and find the data that they use in JSON format.

How I've solved this is to, using python:

1. parse the webpage with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
url = "https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/RE9Rq/1/"
raw = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(raw.text, "lxml")
```

2. Locate the script that has all the data that we want, and remove some unnecessary characters:

```
raw_data = soup.find_all("script")[1]
string_data = str(raw_data).replace("\\", "")
```

3. Nested inside of this mess of a string is the JSON that contains our data. So, we can use regex to find and extract it:

```
raw_json = (
    "{" + re.findall(r"\"data\":\{.*?\]", string_data, flags=re.MULTILINE)[1] + "}}"
)
```

4. This is still technically in string form, so we need to parse it using the `json` library:

```
data = json.loads(raw_json)["data"]
```

Now, you should have all the data, so you can look through it, find whatever pieces you want, and transform it into a dataframe (`pandas.DataFrame.from_records()` is quite helpful)

---

full code:

```
import requests
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/RE9Rq/1/"
raw = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(raw.text, "lxml")
raw_data = soup.find_all("script")[1]
string_data = str(string_data).replace("\\", "")
raw_json = (
    "{" + re.findall(r"\"data\":\{.*?\]", raw_data, flags=re.MULTILINE)[1] + "}}"
)

data = json.loads(raw_json)["data"]
```